# AWS ECS Fargate deployment optimization not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, github-actions, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

My situation right now is that I have a CI/CD pipeline set up in **GitHub Actions**, this workflow does the job of deploying my app container into **ECS Fargate** with a set of configs needed to work. To manage my infrastructure I use **Terraform** to set up an Application Load Balancer and the service inside my ECS app Cluster among a lot of other things that I use in my stack.

So before I started doing some optimization the pipeline took around **15 minutes** *(this is way to much for hotfixes, that's the main reason I'm doing this)* and after some changes in the **Dockerfile** and **Docker build** stage I managed to take this down to around **8 minutes**, in which 3 minutes are used in the GitHub release tag, Docker build and push of the image to ECR and the remaining 5 minutes are used in the ECS deploy.

The thing is I found this documentation from AWS in [Best Practices - Speeding up deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/deployment.html) for ECS and decided to do some changes in this stage too. After reading [Load balancer health check parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/load-balancer-healthcheck.html), [Load balancer connection draining](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/load-balancer-connection-draining.html) and [Task deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/service-options.html) I changed these configs:

1. **(Terraform)** In the Application Load Balancer

   - *deregistration_delay* from **100** to **70**
   - *health_check interval* from **30** to **5**
   - *health_check healthy_threshold* from **5** to **3**
   - *health_check timeout* to **4**
2. **(Terraform)** In the ECS Service

   - *health_check_grace_period_seconds* from **100** to **20**
3. **(task-definition)** In the *containerDefinitions*:

   - *stopTimeout* = **10**

So I was expecting to go down from **150** to **15 seconds** just from *health_check* changes and even more because of the other settings but at the time of forcing a new deploy to check the results I got almost the exact same deploy time with the same **5 minutes** used in the ECS stage.

So I would like to know what setting or process am I missing to make the changes work, I looked around in my AWS console and the values where changed so the **Terraform apply** did work but the ECS stage definitely is taking the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I find that basic ECS Fargate deployments are *way* slower compared to ECS EC2 deployments. Which makes sense as Fargate has more work to do. It needs to identify a host etc, whereas EC2 hosts are there, running, may have some of the required Docker layers already downloaded.

I generally find Fargate deployments take 2.5-4mins (eu-west-1) so you really need to identify where the lag is.

Some things worth checking, which might help point you in the correct direction:

- When do health checks start on the new task? If they start at 4mins then the deployment is only taking 1 minute.
- The overall deployment time includes time to stop + deregister the old task(s) - how long is that taking?
- How long does it take for you to start your application on an empty docker service?

Comment: Something to also consider is the size of the docker image. Smaller images can get into the RUNNING state faster.